# ValueError: Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-15-d27c936e2293> in <module>()

Tags: python, file, csv

I am trying to read the data from a csv file and I am getting this error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d27c936e2293> in <module>()
 11 for row in header:
 12     # row = [Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj. close]
---> 13     date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
     14     open_price = float(row[1])
     15     high = float(row[2])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
360     if not found:
361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data 'D' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Here's my code:

```
import csv 
from datetime import datetime 

path ="google_stock_data.csv"
file = open (path, newline = '')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next (reader)

data = [] 
for row in header: 
# row = [Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj. close]
   date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
   open_price = float(row[1])
   high = float(row[2])
   low = float(row[3])
   close = float(row[4])
   volume = float(row[5])
   adj_close = float(row[6])

data.append([date, open_price, high, low, close, volume, adj_close])

print(data[0])
```

NOTE: The data in the file looks like this:

```
Date      Open        High        Low          Close      Volume      Adj Close

8/19/14 585.002622  587.342658  584.002627  586.862643  978600  586.862643
8/18/14 576.11258   584.512631  576.002598  582.162619  1284100 582.162619
8/15/14 577.862619  579.382595  570.522603  573.482626  1519100 573.482626
8/14/14 576.182596  577.902645  570.882599  574.652582  985400  574.652582
```

Why is that? Isn't the data being converted to the proper type? Please help. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the contents of the `google_stock_data.csv`?

Comment: Date Open High Low Close Volume Adj Close
8/19/14 585.002622 587.342658 584.002627 586.862643 978600 586.862643
8/18/14 576.11258 584.512631 576.002598 582.162619 1284100 582.162619
8/15/14 577.862619 579.382595 570.522603 573.482626 1519100 573.482626
8/14/14 576.182596 577.902645 570.882599 574.652582 985400 574.652582

Comment: `for row in header` is looping over the header, not the data rows. Close-voting as typo.

Comment: It should be `FileHandle = open("google_stock_data.csv", "r")` `for line in FileHandle:` or `with open("google_stock_data.csv") as FileHandle:`.

Answer (score 0):

You're example code is close, but there are a few issues:
First, there's a typo in the for loop, it should be

```
for row in reader:
```

Second, it doesn't look like the datetime parser supports the date format where months and days are not zero filled.  Therefore, use dateutil.parser:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
date = parse(row[0], dayfirst=False)
```

Finally, csv doesn't like multiple spaces between fields.  But you can define your own dialect which will solve it:

```
csv.register_dialect('dataformat', delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
reader = csv.reader(file, dialect='dataformat')
```

skipinitialspace will gobble up the extra spaces between fields